# Скрыть метку в AR. UNITY

Tags: c#, unity3d, ar

Как я понял, картинка с тату не прозрачная, а белая, например. Но потом этот цвет "перекрашивается" под цвет кожи. 
Вопрос: как реализовать такое? https://youtu.be/v3rtxatKy0Y

Изначально задача просто скрыть метку

Comment: Решил) Спасибо)

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_h12z2AbZA

Просмотри это видео тут достаточно детально показана схема, то что ты скинул на видео это Image Recognition.

Надеюсь ты знаешь, как пользоваться Vuforia + Unity. Создаешь нужную тебе разметку, потом помещаешь ее на руку. По разметке, вылезают нужные тебе картинки, и дальше у тебя просто идет, выбор нужно изображения, по вопросам пиши отвечу)

Comment: Ссылка =/= ответ